# Highcharts: How to access range values in formatter for "columnrange" type?

Tags: highcharts

I want to customize the tooltips of my Highcharts graph. The y-axis is of type "columnrange", i.e. it has an interval for the y-value:

```
    series: [{
        data: [
            [-0.547571175, 0.401498266],
            [-0.960011899, 0.444655955],
            [-0.660727717, 0.862639688],
            [-0.446911722, 0.660380453],
            [-0.863925256, 0.619544707],
               .......
        ]
    }]
```

The tooltip formatter should look something like this:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var point = this.points[0];
            return '<b>'+ point.x +'</b><br />Interval:'+ point.low +' - '+ point.high;
        },
        shared: true
    }
```

But `point.low` and `point.high` are not defined... How to get these low/high values?

Here you find a sample graph: http://jsfiddle.net/dmN3N/21/

Comment: As I see tooltip displays your low / high value, so I'm not sure what is wrong?

Comment: What you see is the default tooltip. If I want to customize this, I need to define a formatter of my own. And for this reason I need access to the low/high values. Have a look at my own answer : `point.series.data[0].low`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case when you use shared option in tooltip then you need to use this.points[0] etc, if you have shared option disabled you should use this.point

Take look at example shared
http://jsfiddle.net/dmN3N/24/

```
 tooltip: {
        shared:true,
        valueSuffix: '',
        formatter:function(){

            return 'LOW: '+this.points[0].point.low+' HIGH: '+this.points[0].point.high ;
        }
    },
```

and not shared

http://jsfiddle.net/dmN3N/22/

```
tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '',
        formatter:function(){

            return 'LOW: '+this.point.low+' HIGH: '+this.point.high;
        }
    },
```

Comment: I realize this answer is from 3 years ago, but the details have changed. tooltip.formatter is now tooltip.pointFormatter.  Also the this passed is already a point.  this.low and this.high work. this.point.low is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for the formatter of tooltips:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var point = this.points[0];
        return '<b>'+ point.x +'</b><br />Interval:'+ point.series.data[0].low +' - '+ point.series.data[0].high;
    },
    shared: true
}
```

See here for a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/c2gVe/1/

Answer (score 1):

To use the basic pointFormat property you can do:

```
tooltip: { pointFormat: '{point.low}' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't they just `point[0]` and `point[1]` for low and high respectively?

Comment: No, point[1] is undefined. It would be defined if there was a second series, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for your formatter function:

```
formatter: function() {
    var lowPoint = getLow(this.series.data, 'x');
    var highPoint = getHigh(this.series.data, 'x');
    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br />Interval:'+ lowPoint +' - '+ highPoint;
}
```

The `getLow()` and `getHigh()` functions simply take the list of points and returns the low/high points respectively.

Here is one way of implementing it, but you're free to use whatever algorithm you like.

I'm assuming you wanted the highest/lowest `x` value (you can easily get `y` by passing in 'y' as `axis` argument):

```
var getLow = function(list, axis) {
    var low = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if (low !== null) {
            low = list[i][axis] < low ? list[i][axis] : low;
        } else {
            low = list[i][axis];
        }
    }
    return low;
};

var getHigh = function(list, axis) {
    var high = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if (high !== null) {
            high = list[i][axis] > high ? list[i][axis] : high;
        } else {
            high = list[i][axis];
        }
    }
    return high;
};
```

Here is the fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/tKB7y/

Comment: I have only one series, but it's of type 'columnrange'. I.e data consists of a pair min,max for each point.
See the sample here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Comment: @user2092607 Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/z7R2x/ I used your fiddle, and now it display the lowpoint of the interval and the highpoint of the interval. Is that what you're look for?  My original interpretation of your question was that I thought you wanted the lowest point of all the intervals, and highest point of all the intervals...lol

Comment: Your formatter seams not to change the tooltip. What you see in the chart is the default (low/highpoint is displayed by default)...

Comment: @user2092607 So you do want the highest point and lowest point across all the intervals? http://jsfiddle.net/FuEDy/ Sorry I am having hard time understanding what information you want to display in the tool tip

Comment: I just want the interval range being displayed. This is what the default formatter does. But I want to modify this a little bit. If you look at the return string in your formatter sample and compare this with the tooltip displayed in the chart, you will see that your formatter is not working. It's still the default string being displayed in the tooltip.